# Trouble showing an Image Button on HorizontalScroll View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

xml:

```
<com.android.pagescroller.Pager
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" >
</com.android.pagescroller.Pager>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/image_gun"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@drawable/gun"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="right" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/image_hat"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/hat"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Java:

```
 scroller = ((Pager)findViewById(R.id.scrollView));

   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PAGES; i++) {
        View pageView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null);
        ((TextView) pageView.findViewById(R.id.pageText)).setText(jokes[i]);
        //pageView.setBackgroundColor(COLORS[i % COLORS.length]);

        scroller.addPage(pageView);

    }

    im = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.raw.gun);
    im.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(
            ) {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mysound = (MediaPlayer)MediaPlayer.create(PageScrollerActivity.this, R.raw.gun);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm using a Horizontal Scrollview using a pager, I need to make a few Image Buttons common for all the pages in the ScrollView. When I try to accomplish it I'm failing as the OnClick event for Image Button isn't seem to be called. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest putting the buttons outside of the scrollview if they are common to all of of the pages in the scrollview.  Put the handlers in the Activity hosting the scrollview.

Comment: `<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_gun"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/gun"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="right"
  android:onClick="ShootNow"/>`

Comment: `public void ShootNow(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   mysound = (MediaPlayer)MediaPlayer.create(PageScrollerActivity.this, R.raw.gun);
  }
}`

Comment: I put the onClick: ShootNow in the host Activity still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Are you sure that the event handlers are getting set up?  Make sure that the handler code gets executed - log out to the LogCat to make sure that they are getting set up.  Also, are there any errors occurring before the handlers get created?

Comment: You're right. Even a simple ImageButton doesn't seem to be working. The application doesn't even start up.. :(

Comment: If you're not comfortable with it yet the LogCat is your best friend as a developer.  I would advise learning the particulars of it - it's indispensable for finding regressions!

Comment: Thanks @Android Addict. I'll see what I can do.! :(